# The best way to convert Vector into Matrix in Julia?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

Suppose I have a variable `v` of a type `Vector`.

What would be the best / fastest way to just convert it into `Matrix` representation (for whatever reason)?

To clarify, `v''` will do the job, but is it the best way to do this?

Comment: try using `reshape`.

Comment: Just noting that in v0.6, `v''` will no longer work, as this now converts `v` into a row vector, then back into a vector. `reshape` (as described below) is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Reshape should be the most efficient. From the docs:

> **reshape(A, dims):** Create an array with the same data as the given array, but with different dimensions. An implementation for a particular type of array may choose whether the data is copied or shared.

```
julia> v = rand(3)
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.690673 
 0.392635 
 0.0519467

julia> reshape(v, length(v), 1)
3x1 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.690673 
 0.392635 
 0.0519467
```

Comment: We can now use `reshape(v, :, 1)`, instead of finding `length(v)` explicitly. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.reshape

Answer (score 12):

`v[:,:]` is probably the clearest way to do this.

For example:

```
julia> v=[1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
1
2
3

julia> m=v[:,:]
3x1 Array{Int64,2}:
1
2
3

julia> ndims(m)
2
```

Comment: This will allocate, so better to use reshape

Answer (score 2):

Or just use:

```
v = [1, 2, 3]
hcat(v)
```

Result:

```
3×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
```